# Can't force braces to the next line in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just got myself Intellij Idea and it's running very smoothly, but a problem I have is that I can't force the braces on the next line. I looked up for answers on the web, and found out that I can change this option in Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java, then select "Next Line" for braces placement. I tried that, but it did nothing. I type a class or a function, the braces still appear on the same line. It only forces it into the next line when I reformat the whole file. Is there any way to change this or is this just a bug?

[image]

Comment: This is not a good Idea to do that! Based on google coding standard for java programs it suggests to place bracket in the same line as function name. See [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: Good thing we don't all work at Google.

Answer (score 0):

IDE does not auto-format on brace typing. Please vote for a related request: [IDEABKL-788](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-788).